# MS Access 2016 - parameter input popup when passing a parameter using a where condition to open a report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

My question is a simple one, and I cannot find a simple answer to this question, after much searching. Many of the answers are about more complex coding situations that are difficult for me to relate to this question.

I am opening a report from a form.   I can specify the username  parameter as "bill" and the report displays only the records where "bill" is the user name. If I manually change "bill" to "tom" it still works and displays the records where the user name is "tom"

```
Private Sub Command11_Click()

Const cstrForm2 As String = "Report1"

 'DoCmd.OpenReport cstrForm2, acViewPreview, WhereCondition:="[username]=" & "'bill'"


End Sub
```

If I use the following code, and put in Me.username (username being the name of the textbox, and is unbounded)

```
DoCmd.OpenReport cstrForm2, acViewPreview, WhereCondition:="[username]=" & Me.username
```

MS Access prompts me to enter the parameter value. If I enter the parameter value, "tom" or "bill" I get the correct data on the report.

How do I get rid of the parameter input box, basically how do I pass the correct format of parameter value to get the result I want? It may have to do with using a combination of quotes and other characters, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create a query first. Apparently creating a query avoids the problem.

Create a query for the table in question, and in the criteria section of the query, under design view :

enter the following under criteria

```
[Forms]![Form1]![username]
```

Where Form1 is the name of the form and username is the name of the textbox.

When you get the query running, create a report using the query as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

You still need the single-quotes:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport cstrForm2, acViewPreview, WhereCondition:="[username]='" & Me!username.Value & "'"
```